# Laravel 5.5 - Load migrations from nested packages

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm working currently on some Laravel packages and have a question about integrating nested packages.

I've packages for Tagging & Roles and would like to integrate them into another Blogging Packages.

But I'm not able to load the migrations from the nested (Tagging & Roles) packages.

I'm currently trying to load the Service Provider of the packages within the BlogServiceProvider (register function). But alway get an error when I try to do an composer update or dump-autoload

```
$this->app->register(
 'OName\Taggy\TaggyServiceProvider'
);

 $this->app->register(
 'OName\Roles\RolesServiceProvider'
);
```

**Composer.json from the Blog Package**

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
   "illuminate/database": ">= 5.0",
   "illuminate/support": ">= 5.0",
    "OName/taggy": "^1.0"
},

"require-dev": {
    "orchestra/testbench": "~3.5",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
},

"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [

        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},

"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "OName\\Blog\\App\\Providers\\BlogServiceProviders"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Composer.json from the Taggy Package**

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "OName\\Taggy\\": "src"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
   "illuminate/database": ">= 5.0",
   "illuminate/support": ">= 5.0"
},

"require-dev": {
    "orchestra/testbench": "~3.5",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
},

"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [

        "tests/TestCase.php",
        "tests/stubs/TopicStub.php",
        "tests/stubs/TagStub.php"
    ]
},

"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "OName\\Taggy\\App\\Providers\\TaggyServiceProvider"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
```

Class 'OName\Taggy\TaggyServiceProvider' not found

Comment: What does your `composer.json` look like?

Comment: Hey @Jeffrey, thanks for your reponse, i added the Blog package composer .json and Taggy package composer.json. Cheers, Stan